# Does Spring boot provide any internal library for generating coverage report

Tags: java, spring-boot, code-coverage, reportgenerator

I am working on an assignment in which I need to generate code coverage report without using any plugin.I have gone through the Spring boot documentation but could not find any article on coverage report generation. Is it possible to generate coverage report without using any plugin like jacoco or maven-surefire-report-plugin or sonarQube. Any input will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

No, It isn't. Spring Boot's maven/gradle plugins does not provide support for code coverage out of the box, you will need to use either JaCoCo or a similar tool.

See:

- [Generate Code Coverage with JaCoCo and spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037013/generate-code-coverage-with-jacoco-and-spring-boot-maven-plugin)
- [Code Coverage and Source Quality Analysis with Spring Boot + Docker + SonarQube + JaCoCo](https://springbootdev.com/2018/01/10/code-coverage-and-source-quality-analysis-with-spring-boot-docker-sonarqube-jacoco/)